# Ignore maven target folder but not package "target"

Tags: java, git, maven, gitignore

I have a problem managing my gitignore file.
My git folder structure looks like this:

- Project1

  - src
  - target
- Project2

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - target
  - target
- Project3

  - src
  - target

.gitignore

I want to ignore all target folders which is generated by maven build process, but not target package(inside Project2) and all files within the packge.
I have tried to use this .gitignore:

```
target/
!Project2/src/main/java/target/
```

The above example is not working out for me.

The problem is that I have many packges and I dont want to explicit ignore the target folder for each one, but rather point out the target package not to ignore.

*** Renaming the package is not an option.

Comment: You have to add `/target` in your `.gitignore` file...

Comment: Your solution is not working for me. It includes all files within Project1/target/classes/* as new files...

Comment: So I know that you are doing it right. Now you need to change it into `.gitignore` now needs to be changed to `target` and add the following line `!/src/**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
**/target/**
!**/src/**
```

The first line will add all targets while the second says to exclude src from the previous ignores.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore